# Cannot serve React app in NX-jsx is not currently enabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I created a react app in a NX workspace using `nx g @nrwl/react:application --js --unitTestRunner=none --e2eTestRunner=none my-project`

Then I developed my project. Finally when I want to run my project using
`nx serve my-project` I get following error:

`Syntax error: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled`

I realized that it is related to babel configuration of project so I
installed `@babel/preset-react @babel/preset-env` and replaced content of
`.babelrc` file

configuration before any change:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@nrwl/react/babel",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic",
        "importSource": "@emotion/react"
      }
    ]
  ],
  "plugins": ["@emotion/babel-plugin"]
}
```

.babelrc after installing packages

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

I also changed `jsx` property in `compilerOptions` of tsconfig.json from
`"react-jsx"` to `"react"`

but when I run `nx serve my-project` again, I get that error again.

What should I do? Is there any solution?

Comment: there is likely a chance that you created some libraries that do not have a babelrc and that is from where this error is being thrown

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the lib generator, when you create a react lib ,I only tried publishable, it doesnt add the babelrc file so you have to add it yourself..just copy it from your app. Its a bug atm